# AHK does not understanding tag wb

Tags: internet-explorer, com, autohotkey

I am trying to write some code that basically loads an internet page and clicks a button on that page.

I have been searching the internet for any tutorials or help, but I can't seem to find anything about getting this to work. There was something about a COM, but it went over my head.

Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated, but as it is the below code is just coming up with an error.

```
"Error:Call to nonexistent function.

Spcecifically: ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

***This is the code I have***

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Navigate("Google.com")
wb.Visible := True
```

Comment: Why not using google with the words "autohotkey web simulate click"? You find enough stuff to go further....

Comment: I have tried searching the web, and everything is saying about using COMS and the tag "wb" is a know tag by ahk, however when I try use it, I get the error with it not understanding the tag "wb", every place I go to try find this out they don't say how to get "wb" to work, they just say it should work.

Comment: Some examples,

https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=427
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/97459-wbdocumentalltagsdiva-index-1innertext-issue/
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/97748-documentall-with-variables/

They don't explain how to get it to work, just that it is a feature that should just work

Answer (score 0):

You are close!  `wb` is arbitrary.  It's just what you call your instance of IE created by ComObjCreate.

Try:

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := true
wb.Navigate("google.com", "")
While wb.readyState!=4 || wb.document.readyState!="complete" || wb.busy
    Sleep 150
wb.Document.getElementByID("Element_ID").click()
```

And let us know the results.

Comment: Sorry PGilm, I have only just seen this. I run out of ideas to try get this to work and all explanations were going well over my head, and was trying other methods. However, I am happy to pick it back up and give this a try.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,

I have tried this and I am getting the error 

0x80010108 - The object invoked has disconnected from its client. 

I'll research and add my findings up here

Comment: That is a strange error, usually associated with Windows Update fails, or logon difficulties.  What is the website you want to navigate to, and what is the button or element you want to click on using the script?  Be specific as you can, please . . .

Comment: (you seem rather knowledgeable, so bare with me, because I'm really not) 

its telling me it the line

While wb.readyState!=4 || wb.document.readyState!="complete" || wb.busy

I'm trying to automate a login to an intranet page, and the button is a link to a javascript script I'm guessing. But it basically opens up a Windows Security login on a separate pop up window. I have managed to get something to kind of work in VBA so I'm sure it can be done.